# Replacing word with point value in php

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel

I want to grab the input text from the user. I want to compare the words the user used to a DB of words that also has a value.

Right now I made an array that takes the input runs it to the DB and returns the value. The issue I'm having with that is it's not in the right order.

```
    // GETTING THE ARRY OF WORDS FROM entry_body( $entry_text)
    $entry_text = $request->only('entry_body');

    // REMOVE THE KEY AND JUST GET THE STRING VALUE
    $entry_text = array_pull($entry_text,"entry_body");
    $entry_noTag = strip_tags($entry_text);

    // CONVERTE THE STRING ARRAY
    $entry_explode = explode(" ", $entry_noTag);

    // COUNT THE LENTH OF THE WORDS AND DIVIDE IT BY 3
    $entry_lenth = count($entry_explode);

    $new_array = array();
    // EACH WORD GETS ANALAYZED 
    $matched_words = Words::whereIn('word', $entry_explode)->get();
    foreach($matched_words as $mw){
            $new_array[]=$mw->word;
            $value_array[$mw->word]=$mw->value;
    }

    $arrayOfWords = array();
    foreach ($entry_explode as $word) {
        if (in_array($word,$new_array)) {
            $arrayOfWords['yes_words'][] = $word;
        } else {
            $arrayOfWords['no_word'][] = $word;
        }
    }
```

I also need to get the words to be in 3 groups in order. I did this to get the groups in the right order.

```
    $entry_math = number_format($entry_lenth / 3);


    return array_chunk($entry_explode, $entry_math);
```

And this is the output that I get

```
     [
      [
        "Hey",
        "Jude,",
        "don't",
        "make",
        "it",
        "bad",
        "Take",
        "a",
        "sad",
        "song"
       ],
     [
        "and",
        "make",
        "it",
        "better",
        "Remember",
        "to",
        "let",
        "her",
        "into",
        "your"
       ],
       [
        "heart",
        "Then",
        "you",
        "can",
        "start",
        "to",
        "make",
        "it",
        "better."
       ]
      ]
```

I need to replace the words with the numbers that I get from the $value_array but I'm not 100% sure on how I should do that.

This is what the $value_array looks like.

```
 {
   "a": "0",
   "and": "0",
   "bad": "1",
   "better": "2",
   "can": "2",
   "heart": "3",
   "her": "3",
   "hey": "3",
   "into": "0",
   "it": "2",
   "let": "1",
   "make": "1",
   "remember": "3",
   "sad": "1",
   "song": "2",
   "start": "3",
   "take": "1",
   "then": "2",
   "to": "2",
   "you": "2",
   "your": "2"
 }
```

Comment: I don't get it where is your problem exactly?

Comment: I need to get the number and not the word. Put when I print out the number it's not in the right order. For example, I need 'Hey' to say 2

Comment: Where the number comes from?

Comment: I have a DB of words that have a value. I will edit my  questions to show what the output looks like from $value_array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with simple foreach,

See this example,

Consider this arrays.

```
$input = ['hi', 'you', 'me', 'and','others'];

$database_input = [
    'hi' => 1,
    'you' => 5,
    'me' => 4,
    'and' => 3,
    'others' => 2,
    'some' => 6,
    'extra' => 7,
    'elements' => 8
];
```

To get an array with this output

```
Array
(
    [hi] => 1
    [you] => 5
    [me] => 4
    [and] => 3
    [others] => 2
)
```

All you need to do is,

```
$input = ['hi', 'you', 'me', 'and','others'];

$database_input = [
    'hi' => 1,
    'you' => 5,
    'me' => 4,
    'and' => 3,
    'others' => 2,
    'some' => 6,
    'extra' => 7,
    'elements' => 8
];

$output = [];

foreach($input as $item) {
    if(array_key_exists(strtolower($item), $database_input))
        $output[strtolower($item)] = $database_input[strtolower($item)];
}
```

Here is the basic logic how things can be done.

I've created php paste that works with your input see link below:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63c1a0eb669df43a92a15104340f528a76a2cfb0